# AngularJs Multiple Calling of same directive is causing issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a hard time getting a simple directive to work. I have a directive which will change the button color when I click on it and set it back to the original color when I click on it again.

Basically it is a mark button, which will let you mark something and changes it's color when you are done marking.

In order to change the color I make use of `ng-class` which sets an active class whenever a scope variable is set. It works fine when I use that directive once, when I use multiple instances it starts causing issues.

Here is the code.

```
app.directive('myNeeds',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/needs.html',
        // text binding
        scope: {
            needkey: '@needKey',
            needvalue: '@needValue',
            needcity: '@needCity'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.isNeed = false;
            element.bind('click',function() {
                scope.isNeed = !scope.isNeed;
            });
        }
    }
});

<span class="star">
    <i class="dse-sprite ico-blue-star hand" ng-class="{active:isNeed}"></i>
</span>
```

Now lets say I call this directive twice on a page, no matter which button I have clicked it will add the active class to the latest or the last button on the page.

Comment: Can you make a plunker or fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Maybe a JSFiddle or Plunker would help in diagnosing what is going on. This sounds like an issue with shared scopes but its hard to say just based on the information provided.

Comment: your code is not even using the myNeeds directive?!

Comment: All seems to be working , i made a fiddle and it is fine, actually my directive has some other code which is using a service, so it seems to be a glitch there